# Mounting NAS on system start

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab, nas

I know this is a question that has been asked many, many, many times but I can't find a solution that fits all my criteria.  And I apologise if there is a duplicate for this problem, if there is I can't find it.

I'm using a Raspberry running Rasbian, totally up to date.
It's connected on wifi, it cannot be cabled.
My network storage is a Synology DiskSation with SMB and NFS running.
My users all have access to the NAS.
I need the mount to be created when the desktop loads/user logs in.

I've tried the fstab route, with cifs I get a protocol error, I don't think then as understands cifs, with nfs I cannot get passed a security problem, but I know my users are setup correctly, they work with every manual mount.  However, I have read somewhere that 'fstsb' runs way before any wifi will be running, so it won't work anyway.
I've tried going the 'rc.local' route, but I can't get any script to run.
I've tried the '.bashrc' route, this works perfectly but only when a user opens the terminal window.
I've tried the System Service route, but there are either problems with the [unit] or What/Where syntax and I can't find specific raspbian options.

At this point I've run out of unix knowledge and blue google results!

if anyone has achieved this specific mounting issue, could you please put me out of my misery and let me know the right way to go?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not need access to NAS at boot time, you could use *autofs*. It will automatically mount the target on demand when the mount point is accessed.

[Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) contains examples for both NFS and CIFS.